# How to find the last row of a non-active workbook and copy/paste

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write my code to be more robust so it does not rely on active workbooks, but I cannot figure it out

the logic of wb.sheets. should tell VBA to perform every following action in the line on the specified wb. But it is not woking for some reason. If the book is not active, my code will not work.

```
Do Until IsEmpty(file) <> False  
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=DataPath & file
        Windows(ReportName).Activate 'I would like to not have to activate windows
        LastRow = Sheets(Sheets.count).Cells(Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row 'i.e. how would this code be written if it is not the active window?
        Windows(file).Activate 'same same but different 
        LastRowTemp = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        Range(Cells(2, 48), Cells(LastRowTemp, 48)).Copy Workbooks(ReportName).Sheets(ws).Range("A" & LastRow + 1) 'how do i copy from 1 wb to a 2nd, assuming both are non-active?
```

Thanks!
Kyle

I expect to be able to have a code that does not rely on active workbooks. I.e. `LastRow = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.count).Cells(Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable for the workbook. You should also declare all your variables, and fully qualify all your calls to `Cells`, `Sheets`, etc, by actually specifying what sheet and workbook you want.

If you just call (for example) `Sheets.count`, VBA assumes you're asking how many worksheets are in the active workbook. Similarly, `Rows.count` will be assumed to mean the number of rows in the active worksheet.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim lastWs As Worksheet

Dim lastRow As Range

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=DataPath & File)
Set lastWs = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)

Set lastRow = lastWs.Cells(lastWs.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row
' etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

`Set` your workbooks and sheets. Then you can just call them by variable name.

- `cWb` = Current Workbook
- `cWs` = Current Worksheet
- `MS` = Master Worksheet (where you are pasting)

---

```
Dim MS As Workbook
Dim cWb As Workbook
Dim cWs As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long

Set MB = Workbooks(ReportName).Sheets(ws)

Do Until IsEmpty(file) <> False

    Set cWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=DataPath & file)
    Set cWs = wb.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    lr = ws.Range("E" & cWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```